# Distance and Norm in Linear Subspace

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $(X, \|\cdot\|)$ be a finite dimensional normed space, with corresponding metric $d$. Let $L$ be a proper linear subspace of $X$. Prove that there exists $x\in X$ such that $d(x, L) = \|x\| = 1$, where $d(x, L) = \inf\{ d(x, s) : s \in L \}$. Does this even make sense? I am new to this and I am mixed up. Thanks.

Comment: The problem statement makes sense. What are your concerns?

Comment: what clue can i use to find the x? because L be a proper linear subspace of X

Comment: E.g. you could look at the function $x\mapsto d(x,L)$ on the unit sphere $\{x\in X\mid \|x\|=1\}$. Does it have a maximum? If yes, what is the maximum and where is it? And if you can define an inner product you can look at the orthogonal space $L^\top=\{x\in X\mid \langle x,y\rangle =0 \text{ for all $y\in L$}\}$.

Comment: oh yah.. great! thanks!!

Comment: I think you have to add completeness of $X$. For example for $X=\mathbb{Q}^2$ if you choose $L=\{(q_1,q_2)\in\mathbb{Q}^2:\ q_1=-q_2\}$ the extremal points for $d(x,L)$ on the unit sphere would be $\pm(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\notin\mathbb{Q}^2$.

Comment: Yes, but the space is finite dimensional, so it is complete.

Comment: If the underlying field is $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. Yes, in that case we will require completeness.I am not used to seeing vector spaces over fields other than $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$, though.

Comment: @humanStampedist: usually a normed space is a real or complex vectot space.